# Comprobacion en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas en una base de datos. Una tabla es la de `usuarios` y la otra es la de `control`. En la tabla de `control` se registra la hora de entrada y salida de cada usuario.

Tabla `usuarios`

```
   pk | login    |   nombre     | email
   ========================================================
    1    Usuario    Usuario     usuario1@usuario.com
    2    Usuario2   Usuario     usuario2@usuario.com
    3    Usuario3   Usuario     usuario3@usuario.com
```

Tabla `control`

```
pk_control | fk_usuario |      hora_inicio    |    hora_final
===================================================================
    1            1         2019-05-09 08:00:00 2019-05-09 16:00:00
    2            2         2019-05-09 08:00:00 2019-05-09 16:00:00
```

Mi idea es crear una consulta en la que me devuelva el `pk` del usuario que no ha registrado su `hora_inicio` y su `hora_final` en el día de hoy.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Qué valor tiene de forma predeterminada hora_inicio y hora_final?

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras de forma predeterminada tienen `null`

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que mientras no den su hora de inicio y hora final, esos campos no se llenan, por lo cual, estarían nulos. si ese es el caso, utiliza una consulta como la siguiente:

```
    Select u.pk from usuarios u, control c
    where c.fk_usuario=u.pk and c.hora_inicio is null and c.hora_final is null
```

Comment: Este comentario vale para las dos respuestas (que son practicamente iguales). Suponiendo que efectivamente guarda null cuando no se registra la entrada, basta con preguntar solamente por ella. Seria muy raro (y un grave error del sistema) si se registrara una salida sin una entrada. Y es preferible usar el modo canonico de un inner join, y no el modo antiguo que usaba oracle para construir las consultas.

Comment: Esta opción la he utilizado, pero claro, yo me refiero a los usuarios que no registran en cada día, por ejemplo, que me dé como resultado los usuarios que no se registren mañana y así sucesivamente durante todos los dias.

Comment: En tu pregunta especificas que sea de hoy, me estás confundiendo con lo que pides ahora. Para eso que pides creo que te haría falta algún campo que verifique su faltante o algo similar. lo que se me ocurre, es que tuvieras un campo que funcione como "check" que se llene al final del día, y sólo lo compruebas en la consulta que se check no esté lleno.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo Perdona por las molestias, quizás no me expliqué lo sificientemente bien.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo No entiendo muy bien lo del campo `check`. Pienso que quizás poniendo un campo que tenga `3 valores: 0,1,2` suponiendo que `0 = a null`, `1=hora entrada` y `2=hora de salida` pero nose como poder hacer para que cada día ese campo se quede en `0`

Comment: el campo `check`sería para comprobar si ya fue reportado como faltante.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces el insert en la tabla de control, si no ha habido inserciones con los valores de hora_inicio y hora_final, se insertarán como nulos (Entendiendo que la creación de la tabla lo haya definido asi) Con lo cual, tira de clave foranea y obten los resultados:

```
select us.pk
from usuarios us inner join control co on us.pk = co.fk_usuario
where co.hora_inicio is null and co.hora_final is null;
```

Comment: Esta opción la he utilizado, pero claro, yo me refiero a los usuarios que no registran en cada día, por ejemplo, que me dé como resultado los usuarios que no se registren mañana y así sucesivamente durante todos los dias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes determinar que registros de usuario no tienen registro de control utilizando una sub-consulta y el operador `not exists`, por ejemplo, para determinar qué usuarios no tienen registro el día de hoy, la consulta quedaría algo como:

```
select *
  from usuarios
 where not exists (select 1
                     from control
                    where control.fk_usuario = usuario.pk
                      and date(control.hora_inicio) = date(curdate())
                  )
```

Comment: He estado haciendo comprobaciones con tu script, por ejemplo con el día de hoy pero cuando realizo un registro con `usuario1`, me aparecen todos los usuarios y se supone que solo debe aparecer `usuario2` y `usuario3`

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el campo `hora_inicio` tiene la misma fecha que retorna `curdate()`?. No se me ocurre otra razón por la que esto pueda fallar.

Comment: qué te devuelve este query: `select fk_usuario, date(hora_inicio), date(curdate()) from control order by hora_inicio desc`